# Use Array Globally

Tags: php

I need to access the array on each function for that purpose i define the array globally but it shows an undefined variable error.

I tried the define a array under the class

```
<?php
new SampleController();

class  SampleController {
    static $array_global = [];

    public function fnc1(){
        $fnc1_array = array('1','2','3');
        self::$array_global['fnc1_array'] = $fnc1_array;
    }

    public function fnc2(){
         print_r(self::$array_global);exit;
         $fnc2_array = array('a','b','c');
         $array_global['fnc2_array'] = $fnc2_array;
    }
}
?>
```

The `fnc1()` calls first and `fnc2()` calls after clicking a button from html. I expect like this access the array in each function it is possible

```
<?php
new SampleController();

class  SampleController {
    global $array_global;
    $array_global = array();

    public function fnc1(){
        $fnc1_array = array('1','2','3');
        $array_global['fnc1_array'] = $fnc1_array;
    }

    public function fnc2(){
        $fnc2_array = array('a','b','c');
        $array_global['fnc2_array'] = $fnc2_array;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does it really need to be global, not a class property?

Comment: what *ever* you are trying to do, there *is* a better way without globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a variable that's shared by all instances of a class, it should be a static class property. You access it using `self::$variable`

```
class  SampleController {
    static $array_global = [];

    public function fnc1(){
        $fnc1_array = array('1','2','3');
        self::$array_global['fnc1_array'] = $fnc1_array;
    }

    public function fnc2(){
        $fnc2_array = array('a','b','c');
        self::$array_global['fnc2_array'] = $fnc2_array;
    }

    public function printArray() {
        var_dump(self::$array_global);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/TRK6iS)

Comment: It shows Some  Access to undeclared static property error;but i think the definition is correct

Comment: I mistakely the definition variable in above class. From its ok.but When accession that variable in fnc2()  like i call the fnc1() and call fnc2() to print the array $array_global variable it contains empty

Comment: You have to print `self::$array_global`.

Comment: Yes i used like that print_r(self::$array_global); but it contains empty array

Comment: when i print the array in fnc1() it conains index and values .Although i print in fnc2() it shows an empty

Comment: in print_r(self::$array_global) -> empty; var_dump(self::$array_global)->array(0) { }

Comment: Are you doing these calls in different executions of the PHP script from HTML? Class properties don't persist between script executions. You need to use a session variable.

Comment: yes i am sure i call first fnc1 and second fnc2 .i think mistake in class definiton intialy i calls a class definition on top new SampleController();is it ok